# Gaussian Process for noise free data

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, covariance-matrix, gaussian-process, bayesian-optimization

In a Gaussian Process model, the covariance function is given as follows:
$$
C\left(y_{*} \mid y_{d}\right)=K\left(x_{*}, x_{*}\right)-K\left(x_{*}, x_{d}\right) K\left(x_{d}, x_{d}\right)^{-1} K\left(x_{d}, x_{*}\right)
$$

Where $x_{*}$ is the query point, and $x_{d}$ are all historical observations.

Assume observations are noise-free. I am wondering that when adding new observations (i.e., $x_{d}$ is updated as $x_{d+1}$), does $C\left(y_{*} \mid y_{d+1}\right)$ always smaller than $C\left(y_{*} \mid y_{d}\right)$, and how to prove if this statement is true?

Comment: Yes it is true. Use this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/187637/8298) but split $x_0$ in two parts, one part from the $y_d$ and one part from the additional observation.